# faSmileO undefined control sequence

Tags: fontawesome, fontawesome5

I am using `\usepackage{fontawesome5}` and pdflatex in order to display some icons such as `\faCheck` or `\faExclamation` which work fine.

If I try in the same way to display a smiley with `\faSmileO` I get  instead an *undefined control sequence* error. Why?

Comment: There is no `\faSmileO` (uppercase `o`), but only `\faSmile` and `\faSmile[0]`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Thanks. \faSmile[0] is what I wanted I found the uppercase o version in http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Comment: In linked `symbols-a4.pdf` (version 19 Jan 2017), `\faSmilO` is listed under Table 504: `fontawesome` Web-Related Icons, page 187. Noted that `fontawesome` and `fontawesome5` are two different packages hence there are some differences between them, and you just encountered one.

Comment: @user1583209 There is no `\faSmile[0]` either, the command is `\faSmile[regular]`. `\faSmile[0]` only appears to work because of some fallback behavior (you should have gotten a warning about that)